# Float point binary to decimal?

Tags: binary

I know how to convert from float binary to decimal if exponent and mantissa are explicitly given, but what about these examples:

0.11 = ? 
0.101 = ?

I know the values are 75 and 625, but how the conversion process is implemented?

Comment: Do you mean floating-point to decimal? And is this IEEE754 floating-point? Or another type?

Comment: IEEE754 and yes, i mean floating-point to decimal

Answer (score 0):

To convert some fraction `f` (where `0 ≤ f < 1`) to a sequence of digits in base `B`, perform this algorithm:

```
mantissa = 0
exponent = 0

while f > 0 and exponent > minExponent:
    p = f * B
    i = floor(p)
    f = p - i

    mantissa = mantissa * B + i
    exponent -= 1
```

`minExponent` is a constant that limits the size of the output.  The final values of `mantissa` and `exponent` are such that `mantissa * B^exponent == f` (the original `f`) (under the constraint of `exponent >= minExponent`.

Note that the algorithm does not care how the computer internally represents fractions.  It could be binary or trinary or [sexagesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal); it doesn't matter.  The algorithm converts `f` to an integer which, when divided by the appropriate power of `B`, is equal to `f`.

Note also that `mantissa` needs to be capable of storing as many digits as `-minExponent`.  This may mean you need to use a big-integer library, depending on what your programming language provides.

Here's a complete Python script that demonstrates the algorithm:

```
from __future__ import division
from math import floor

def convert(f, B, minExponent):
    mantissa = 0
    exponent = 0

    while f > 0 and exponent > minExponent:
        p = f * B
        integer = floor(p)
        f = p - integer

        mantissa = mantissa * B + integer
        exponent -= 1

    print "result = %d * %d^%d" % (mantissa, B, exponent)

convert(3/4, 10, -40)
convert(5/8, 10, -40)
convert(1/3, 10, -40)
```

Here's the output:

```
result = 75 * 10^-2
result = 625 * 10^-3
result = 3333333333333333031620069604124830728192 * 10^-40
```

Comment: I want to thank you for the given effort, but I needed to know this:

.. 2 1 0 . -1 -2 ..
.. 1 1 0 .  1  1 ..

left from point: 1*2^2 + 1*2^1 + 0*2^0 = 6
right from point: 1*(2^(-1)) + 1*(2^(-2)) = 1*0.50 + 1*0.25 = 0.75

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  Perhaps you should edit your question to describe, in precise detail, what the input to the program should be, and what the corresponding output should be, and give examples.

Comment: You can perform the algorithm by hand if you wish.  Which part of it do you not understand?

Comment: I understand the algorithm, but I wanted short way (something like your algorithm) to find the decimal value from floating-point binary value. And I found it...
So, with all due respect, thanks again... and discussion can be closed :D